# Only Light or Dark for an Angular Material Theme?

Tags: angular, angular-material, themes

Do you have to choose just Light or Dark for an Angular Material Theme?  I've checked the latest tool of Angular Material:

https://material.io/tools/color/#!/?view.left=0&view.right=0

And it shows three options, light, dark, and one without light or dark.

But when I go to my mat-theme.scss it seems I can only pick 'mat-light-theme' or 'mat-dark-theme'.  Is there an options for neither light or dark, as the ColorPicker seems to show.

Answer (score 3):

Nevermind!!!

I found this wonderful [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PsgZjFTAleI), by Tomas Trajan, the helps to explain how it all gets laid out, via video, or you can go to a literary explanation [here](https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/the-complete-guide-to-angular-material-themes-4d165a9d24d1).

To answer it quickly, the differences are darker, lighter, and default, but that's only used by specific definition of an element's color schema.  The Material Themes in the mat-theme.scss, are only defined mat-light-theme or mat-dark-theme.

Hopefully Tomas's article helps to explain it to you.  This means the documentation by Angular Material needs some work.  At least that's what I think.